# Co-signing & dying: What if a loan co-signer dies? Is estate of co-signer liable?

Tags: loans, debt, estate-planning, co-sign, death

*A grim and tragic question perhaps, but I'm curious:*

What happens when a person that co-signed on a loan dies? Is the co-signer's *estate* potentially liable until the loan is paid off, the same as if the co-signer had borrowed the money themselves?  Or, does the responsibility for the loan die with the co-signer?  Does the bank/lender take on that risk?

Comment: Can you get insurance on the loan to cover such issues (deaths/disasters/company bankruptcy)? Maybe it is even included by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a Google search on **co-signer death**, which provided a lot of results that looked useful.  The top result (from the *Boston Globe*) basically says "[it depends](http://www.boston.com/business/personalfinance/managingyourmoney/archives/2009/01/death_of_a_cosi.html)".

Comment: I would love to see this answer improved.  Maybe some excerpts of the results that provide a better context and information.

Answer (score 4):

Unless there is a specific clause in the contract, then yes, it would fall to the estate.

Just as assets tend to live on after you, so do your debts; or in this case, your debt-guarantee on behalf of someone else.

Comment: What if there isn't much of an estate?  How does a co-signed loan rank in the priority list of people who get paid with limited assets?

Comment: IANAL: But, likely it would end up in the courts then.  The ranking would include if there the co-signer has put up any specific security, i.e. their house, as co-signing collateral.  In any case, the creditor would stand ahead of regular inheritance by the usual heirs (son/daughter).

Comment: What if there has been no default.  IE someone cosigns on a 3 year Auto loan.  10 months in the cosigner dies but the Primary borrower has not missed any payments and has not had a status change that would allow them to refinance or cause them to default.

Comment: @Chad: That would be the aspect I'd be most curious about, especially if the executors of the estate knew nothing of the loan's existence.  If the lender discovered that the cosigner died, could an inheritor be approached out of the blue to put up a surety bond even if the original borrower was current in his payments?

Comment: @supercat - I am sure they could... what I do not know is what would happen if the estate said no we are not going to do that or what recourse the estate might have against the original borrower.

Comment: @Chad: Suppose the only thing of value in an single-heir estate is a house, and debts total $100,000.  By my understanding, the heir would be entitled to either "buy" the house for $100,000 or decline the inheritance and pay nothing; the decision would be based in large measure upon the total value of the debts in question.  If the heir paid $100,000 which in present condition was worth $120,000 and then spent another $50,000 on personal-use upgrades, and then it turned out that the deceased had another $50,000 of debt the heir knew nothing about, I don't see any equitable way...

Comment: ...of assessing such debt to the heir.  Had such debt been made known earlier, the heir would have been allowed to decline the inheritance, forgoing what--without that other debt--would have been $20,000 in equity, which would be less of a loss to the heir than having to pay a $50,000 debt or abandoning the $50,000 spent on personal-use improvements.

Comment: @supercat Loans that the deceased cosigned should show up on a credit report. obtaining one of those should be a standard part of the executors process.  If you have a specific case you might consider asking your own question.  This question handles the general theory but if you have an applied instance you might be able to get more specific help.

Comment: @Chad: Many loans get reported to credit reporting agencies, but not all do. Would it be fair to say that creditor with a loan which was co-signed with a decedent would be entitled to secure part of the state if it reports the loan to a credit-reporting agency or notifies the estate directly, but its claim could be forfeit if an executor, despite making a good-faith effort to find all creditors, doesn't discover it?

Comment: @Supercat That probably  could(and should) be its own question.  I do not have the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your contract says otherwise, the estate has primary responsibility, but the cosigner is responsible for the remaining balance.

There is never a good reason to co-sign for a loan. Don't do it.

Comment: "never a good reason"? I'd argue there are a *host* of valid scenarios in which co-signing makes a *LOT* of sense

Comment: For the debtor, sure. Name a scenario where accepting liability for someone else's benefit makes sense to the person co-signing.

Comment: let's see - your parent needs a new car but doesn't have the credit rating on their own (but does have the income) to qualify for the 0% but with your help they will?

Comment: Unless you're holding the title on the vehicle, no that doesn't make sense from a financial POV. Mixing business & family is usually a recipe for an unhappy situation.

Comment: @duffbeer703 - guess I am more concerned that my family be doing well than to worry about a little mixing of business with family :)

Comment: @warren - I agree with you there, but I've also witnessed firsthand the distress and despair that can happen when the "business" side goes wrong.

Comment: If your parents have no credit rating but income, take a loan in your own name and give them the money. If you are not willing to do that, you shouldn't be willing to co-sign for them unless you don't understand what it actually means.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I saw this happen once before. The person that died had a life insurance policy that easily covered the obligation. If this a concern to you, then consider the cost of a term life policy.