# What happens if I co-sign a loan and the borrower or debtor dies?

Tags: loans, co-sign, death, estate-planning

What happens if I co-sign a loan and the borrower or debtor (the person that borrowed the money) dies?

Does the co-signer then assume full liability over the loan, i.e. become the new and sole debtor?  Does it vary by type of loan (e.g. mortgage vs. other?)

*(Note:  This is similar to the question [Co-signing & dying: What if a loan co-signer dies? Is estate of co-signer liable?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/co-signing-dying-what-if-a-loan-co-signer-dies-is-estate-of-co-signer-liable), but is asking about the death of the borrower instead, **not** the death of the co-signer.)*

Answer (score 12):

Technically, when you co-sign a loan you are just as liable for payment on the loan as the borrower regardless of their state of necrosis.

The lender will usually go the easiest route to get their money, in the case of going after a living co-signer or working with an executor to navigate the probate process, I think you can guess which one the lender is likely to think is most expedient.